# Why am I stuck in displaying my linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am new to C++ and currently learning linked list. I'm stuck in my very first code of displaying my linked list in certain manner on console like this:

```
1 2
4
```

But when I try to build this it breaks. I am not able to figure out why.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct node {
  int data;
  node *next;
};

class list {
  node *head;

public:
  void display();
};

void list::display() {

  node *newnode;

  newnode = head->next;
  newnode->data = 2;
  newnode->next = new node;
  newnode->data = 2;
  newnode->next = new node;
  newnode->data = 1;
  cout << newnode->data;
  newnode->next = new node;
  newnode->data = 2;
  cout << "\t" << newnode->data;
  newnode->next = new node;
  newnode->data = 1;
  newnode->next = new node;
  newnode->data = 4;
  cout << endl;
  cout << newnode->data;
  newnode->next = NULL;
}

int main() {
  list ab;
  ab.display();
  _getch();
}
```

Comment: `But when I try to build this it breaks.` What exactly "break" means?

Comment: Where do you initialize `head`?

Comment: You have no idea how many memory leaks you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't assigning `newnode` to `newnode->next`, therefore no linked list was being created.

But your code in the linked list doesn't break or anything, it prints the values you wanted, just not in a linked list. The problem may be with `conio.h`, which is of no use in this code. remove `#include <conio.h>` and `getch_();`

To do exactly what you want, the exact way you want, we can create a contructor for `node`, which "automatically" adds the data to the new node.

Then in the display, you have to say that `newnode` is equal to the next node of `newnode`, which is a `new node` of a certain data (`newnode = newnode->next = new node(SOME_DATA)`). Only this way a linked list is being created.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
  int data;
  node *next;
  node(int data){
      this->data = data;
  }
};

class list {
  node *head;
public:
  void display();
};

void list::display() {

  node *newnode = head = new node(2);
  newnode = newnode->next = new node(2);
  newnode = newnode->next = new node(1);
  cout << newnode->data;
  newnode = newnode->next = new node(2);
  cout << " " << newnode->data;
  newnode = newnode->next = new node(1);
  newnode = newnode->next = new node(4);
  cout << endl;
  cout << newnode->data;
  newnode->next = NULL;
}

int main() {
  list ab;
  ab.display();
}
```

Comment: THANKS MAN ITS WORKING NOW!